# Нужны ли запятые в конкретных предложениях: перечисление, придаточные с "и"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Ни одна страна в мире не может сейчас обойтись без внешней(,) мировой финансовой поддержки. Вопрос – на что эта поддержка будет тратиться(,) и как она будет влиять на изменение доходов граждан.* Важно сохранить точность цитаты, переделать не могу. Нужны ли запятые в первом и во втором предложениях? В первом случае вроде как перечисление. Во втором, скорее всего, не надо, ведь тут есть одно зависимое слово: "вопрос (какой?)..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом предложении не перечисление, а пояснение. Его (слово *мировой*) следует выделить запятыми или тире (тире в данном случае лучше).

Во втором предложении можно увидеть бессоюзную связь и выразить ее с помощью двоеточия (*Вопрос: на что эта поддержка...*), а можно увидеть конструкцию типа "А — это Б", которая требует тире. В любом случае *вопрос* — общий член предложения по отношению к двум следующим за ним простым предложениям в составе сложного, посему запятая между ними не нужна.

Answer (score 3):

О! Как хорошо, что Вы спрашиваете только о *нужны ли* и не спрашиваете почему!

*Ни одна страна в мире не может сейчас обойтись без внешней – мировой – финансовой поддержки. Вопрос – на что эта поддержка будет тратиться и как она будет влиять на изменение доходов граждан.*

*Мировую* (поддержку) надо как-то обособить, но в запятых обособление "потеряется", поэтому - на Ваше усмотрение - тире или скобки.